# Lua - Cipher Logic Error Involving string.gsub, Ciphered Output is Not Input

Tags: string, encryption, lua, gsub

My program seems to be experiencing logical errors. I have looked it over multiple times and even written another program similar to this one (also seems to have the same error). I cannot figure out what is wrong, although I think it may involve my usage of string.gsub...

```
repeat
local file = io.open("out.txt", "w")
print("would you like to translate Cipher to English or English to Cipher?")
print("enter 1 for translation to English. enter 2 for translation to Cipher")
tchoice=io.read()
if tchoice=="2" then
print(" enter any text to translate it: ")
rawtextin=io.read()
text=string.lower(rawtextin)
text1=string.gsub(text,"a","q")
text2=string.gsub(text1,"b","e")
text3=string.gsub(text2,"c","h")
text4=string.gsub(text3,"d","c")
text5=string.gsub(text4,"e","j")
text6=string.gsub(text5,"f","m")
text7=string.gsub(text6,"g","r")
text8=string.gsub(text7,"h","g")
text9=string.gsub(text8,"i","b")
text10=string.gsub(text9,"j","a")
text11=string.gsub(text10,"k","d")
text12=string.gsub(text11,"l","y")
text13=string.gsub(text12,"m","v")
text14=string.gsub(text13,"n","z")
text15=string.gsub(text14,"o","x")
text16=string.gsub(text15,"p","k")
text17=string.gsub(text16,"q","i")
text18=string.gsub(text17,"r","l")
text19=string.gsub(text18,"s","f")
text20=string.gsub(text19,"t","s")
text21=string.gsub(text20,"u","w")
text22=string.gsub(text21,"v","t")
text23=string.gsub(text22,"w","p")
text24=string.gsub(text23,"x","u")
text25=string.gsub(text24,"y","n")
text26=string.gsub(text25,"z","o")
text27=string.gsub(text26," ","@")
print(text27)
elseif tchoice=="1" then
print("enter text!")
rawtextin=io.read()
text=string.lower(rawtextin)
text1=string.gsub(text,"q","a")
text2=string.gsub(text1,"e","b")
text3=string.gsub(text2,"h","c")
text4=string.gsub(text3,"c","d")
text5=string.gsub(text4,"j","e")
text6=string.gsub(text5,"m","f")
text7=string.gsub(text6,"r","g")
text8=string.gsub(text7,"g","h")
text9=string.gsub(text8,"b","i")
text10=string.gsub(text9,"a","j")
text11=string.gsub(text10,"d","k")
text12=string.gsub(text11,"y","l")
text13=string.gsub(text12,"v","m")
text14=string.gsub(text13,"z","n")
text15=string.gsub(text14,"x","o")
text16=string.gsub(text15,"k","p")
text17=string.gsub(text16,"i","q")
text18=string.gsub(text17,"l","r")
text19=string.gsub(text18,"f","s")
text20=string.gsub(text19,"s","t")
text21=string.gsub(text20,"w","u")
text22=string.gsub(text21,"t","v")
text23=string.gsub(text22,"p","w")
text24=string.gsub(text23,"u","x")
text25=string.gsub(text24,"n","y")
text26=string.gsub(text25,"o","z")
text27=string.gsub(text26,"@"," ")
print(text27)
end
print("writing to out.txt...")
file:write(text27)
file:close()
print("done!")
print("again? type y for yes or anything else for no.")
again=io.read()
until again~="y"
x=io.read()
```

No errors in the code - What am I missing? I am aware this is not the most efficient way of doing this but I need to figure out what is going wrong before I write a more efficient program using loops and tables.

Sample run (with only significant data included):

```
in:2
in:hi test
out:gb@safs
in:y
in:1
in:gb@safs
out:hq vjvv
```

Comment: edit: found one of the logic errors - q is turned into a and then j. It is safe to assume this is the source of the garbled text, but on my other program I cipher from symbols (@#$%^# etc.) to text and it is still failing. Any ideas why or do I need to post it's code tomorrow? Also, any workarounds for this bug?

Comment: My eyes, my eyes. You should let the computer do the work of repetition. It's infinitely better in that task than you'll ever be. I mean, it can count up to 2^32 without blinking.

Comment: @owlstead                                                                    It was designed to be as simple as it could possibly be, I wanted to fix the bug before complicating things further :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
local decoded = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz @'
local encoded = 'qehcjmrgbadyvzxkilfswtpuno@ '

local enc, dec = {}, {}
for i = 1, #decoded do
   local e, d = encoded:sub(i,i), decoded:sub(i,i)
   enc[d] = e
   dec[e] = d
end

repeat
   local file = io.open("out.txt", "w")
   local text27, rawtextin
   print("would you like to translate Cipher to English or English to Cipher?")
   print("enter 1 for translation to English. enter 2 for translation to Cipher")
   local tchoice = io.read()
   if tchoice == "2" then
      print(" enter any text to translate it: ")
      rawtextin = io.read()
      text27 = rawtextin:lower():gsub('.',enc)
      print(text27)
   elseif tchoice == "1" then
      print("enter text!")
      rawtextin = io.read()
      text27 = rawtextin:lower():gsub('.',dec)
      print(text27)
   end
   print("writing to out.txt...")
   file:write(text27)
   file:close()
   print("done!")
   print("again? type y for yes or anything else for no.")
   local again = io.read()
until again ~= "y"
```

Comment: I understand everything except for the 2nd paragraph and the '.' in text27 = rawtextin:lower():gsub('.',enc), would you mind explaining?

Comment: The `.` is a regular expression which means "any symbol".  Have you read documentation on `gsub` before coding?

Comment: Yes I have, however I missed the bottom part where the documentation talks about patterns, just looked for the "." and managed to find it despite my assumption that the . is not specific to just gmatch. Now I know that . == * . I think I can figure out what paragraph 2 does on my own, thanks! Accepted + upvoted. Also thanks for not mentioning the extreme repetition in my code which I said I would fix when I understood what was going on.